# Cannot convert char* to char

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

My functions are commented out because I was trying to fix this problem first ><. But on when I try to pass my arrays to the functions the compile comes up with an error message.

```
error: cannot convert ‘char*’ to ‘char (*)[7][49]’ for argument ‘1’ to
‘void save(char (*)[7][49])’
```

This happens in my code at lines 63:61, 67:46, and 70:36.

```
//Header
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
using namespace std; 

//function prototype
/* 
Name: deal
Process: takes cards from file into 3d array and 2d array
Input: array name (int),2d array name (int)
Output: none
Dependencies: none 
*/
void deal ( char tablue [7][7][49] , char wastePile [24][24]);
/*
Name: displayCards
Process: Displays cards from array to screen
Input: tablue array (char)
Output to screen: The cards in a solitaire display
Dependencies: None
*/
void displayCards ( char tabalue [7][7][49]);

/*
Name: save
Process: Save tablue to a file
Input: tablue (char)
Output: None
Depnencies: None
*/
void save ( char tablaue [7][7][49] );

// global constants 
ofstream fout; 
ifstream fin;

//main program
int main()
{
//initialize variables  
bool menu = true; 
char choice; 
char tablaue [7][7][49], wastePile [24][24];

//switch menu
 // display options
   cout<< "G.ame" << endl << "Q.uit" << endl;

 //menu
   while ( menu == true )
  { 
   // get user choice
    cin >> choice; 
   // switch 
     switch (choice)
     { 
     // if game
      case 'G':

     //get cards from file
     //deal cards to three "deminsion array" and into waste pile
       // function deal           
         deal ( &tablaue [7][7][49], &wastePile [24][24]);

   //display cards on screen
     // function displayCards
       displayCards ( &tablaue [7][7][49]);

   //save tablaue
     save ( &tablaue [7][7][49]);

   // pause screen
     //system pause

  // break case
     break; 

  //if quit
   case 'Q':

   // end switch
     menu = false; 

 //break case
  break; 
  }
  }
 // display exit screen
 cout<< "Thanks for playing";  

//end program
return 0;
}

//Functions
void deal (char tablue [7][7][49], char wastePile [24][24])
{ 
/*/ initialize variables
char card [40]; 
char space [10];
int rowI, colI, cardI;

// open file
fin.open("card1.txt");

// prime loop
fin << card;

//take in cards
while (fin.good())
{
fin << SPACE;
// fill in array
for ( rowI=0, rowI<7, rowI++)
 {
   for ( colI=0, colI<7, colI++)
    {
     for ( cardI=0, cardI<49, cardI++)
      {
       // check to see if slot should be empty
       if ( rowI < colI)
        {
         tablue[rowI][colI][cardI] = "EMPTY";
        }
      // put card in slot
       else 
        {
         tablue[rowI][colI][cardI] = card;
        }
      }
    }

  }
 //fill waste pile
   for (rowI=0, rowI<24, rowI++) 
    {
     wastePile [rowI] = card; 
    }    
 }*/
}
void displayCards ( char tablue[7][7][49])
{
/*/ initialize variables
int rowI, colI, cardI;

// make space
cout<< endl << endl << "       "; 

// display card
for (rowI =0, rowI<7, rowI++)
{
 for (colI=0, colI<7, colI++)
   {
    for (cardI=0, cardI<7, cardI++) 
     {
      //check for empty slot
       if ( tablue[rowI][colI][cardI] != "EMPTY")
        {
         cout << tablue [rowI][colI][cardI];
        }
       else 
        {
         cout<< "             ";
        }
      //print space
       cout<<"       ";
     }
   }
 }*/
}

void save ( char tablue [7][7][49] )
{
/*

*/
}
```

Comment: annnnd which lines are these?

Comment: Close the browser. Grab K&R C. Read.

Comment: you may wanna reconsider using vectors since u tag it c++

Comment: What about simply `save(tablaue);`? Does that work?

Comment: You're making the common newbie mistake, which is to think that every use of an array must be followed by the size of the array. It's not true, only the *declaration* of the array needs a size.

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `&` or the array size when passing in an array as a parameter.  Simply passing in the name is sufficient, so long as your bas array size and type is declared properly, which it would seem from your code above, they are.

IE:

```
deal ( tablaue, wastePile );
```